# Angular2 [WDS] Disconnected! with nignx

Tags: angular, nginx, webpack

After moving my Angular2 app behind nginx, I see this in my browsers console:

```
GET https://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1486305706324 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[WDS] Disconnected!
```

My nginx proxy is a reverse proxy that listens on subdomain.domain.com port 443 (ssl) and redirects it to localhost on port 4200 for my Angular2 app.
So somewhere in my client app, it tries to resolve the resource on localhost:4200 instead of subdomain.domain.com port 443 (ssl)

I start my client with:

```
ng serve 0.0.0.0
```

I have tried with:

```
ng serve --host subdomain.domain.com --port 443
```

Without any luck.

My package.json looks like this:

...

```
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  }
```

...

I've also tried editing the /node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/webpack.config.js to include:
...

```
  entry: {
    'client': "webpack-dev-server/client?https://subdomain.domain.com"
  host: "https://subdomain.domain.com",
  port: 443,
  https: true

  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'https://subdomain.domain.com'
  },
```

...

UPDATED with nginx configuration:

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/privkey.pem;
 server_name subdomain.domain.com;
 access_log /var/log/nginx.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log debug;
 location / {
  include conf.d/proxy.conf;
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name subdomain.domain.com;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

UPDATED with console log and application structure:

[image: My application structure]

[image: Console log error]

Also without any luck.
Any suggestions to how I can tell my app that runs on a local high port (4200) to resolve ressource on a public domain on another port?

Best regards.

Comment: Is this NGINX on your local server or on production server?

Comment: On the local server that also hosts the angular code.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `ng serve` which is provided by the Angular CLI?

Comment: No there isen't. I just want to be able to serve my angular2 app behind an nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137508/after-update-to-angular-6-wds-disconnected-on-ie-after-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you could build production, then put into a folder, then you config your nginx point to this folder at `subdomain.domain.com`, ng serve run development server, it'll ship live-reload to client, we don't need this in production mode. `ng build --prod` then copy `dist` folder to your web domain folder.

```
server {
    listen 80 subdomain.domain.com;
    listen [::]:80 subdomain.domain.com ipv6only=on;

    root /path/to/dist/or/path/to/copyof/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

for development purpose you could point `subdomain.domain.com root path` to `dist` folder, after that you run `ng build --prod --watch` (*this command will build your project and watch any change, then build again*), then whenever you wanna test something you've made, just refresh your browser manualy

point `root /path/to/dist/or/path/to/copyof/dist;` to a folder like following image

btw, include your css libs, images, fonts, etc in `src/assets` folder. when the CLI build your app, it'll copy `src/assets` folder to `dist/assets` folder, this won't break your style, images, etc.

[image: dist folder]

Comment: Okay, that seems a bit complex for me, as I'am using the server for development, and is testing on the subdomain.domain.com (its not live at the moment) but behind an nginx restricted area. So this means that I need to ng build --prod and copy the dist folder every time I need to test something that I've made?

Comment: no, you could point `subdomain.domain.com` root path to dist folder, when development, you run `ng build --prod --watch`, then whenever you wanna test something you've made, just refresh your browser manualy

Comment: Okay, that might work, I updated my question aobve with the current nginx configuration that proxies the traffic to localhost:4200 and not to a given folder. I will try to modify it, to reflect your example above.

Comment: hey man, did you point this rule `root /path/to/dist/or/path/to/copyof/dist;` to your `dist` folder

Comment: Yes and it almost works. I've updated my question with two images above. It looks like nginx are having some trouble loading files that isen't .htm or .html?

Comment: hey man, this folder is not right folder you need serve, when you run `ng build` command, it'll ship to `dist` folder, this folder same location with `src` folder. the `dist` folder contains all css, js, index.html and `assets` folder. you need point your nginx server point to this `dist` folder, not `src`

Comment: Okay, actually I was pointing nginx to dist folder and not src, the problem was that my assets was not placed in src/assets/ folder, but just in src. Moving the files to /src/assets instead of /src and references them right, fixed the problem!